# Add optional header to WebClient get request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Is there a way to add an optional header to `WebClient` `get()` request?

```
    if (config.getRefresh()) {
        webClient.header("Refresh-Cache", "true");
    }
```

It seems the whole request is chained on `webClient`

```
return webClient
  .get()
  .uri(uri)
  .header("Authorization", BEARER_TOKEN)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(String.class)
  .block();
```

I try to switch to `RequestHeadersSpec` but got this generic type warning

```
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec is a raw type. References to generic type 
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<S> should be parameterized Java(16777788)
```

I know with `post()`, we can do this

```
requestBodySpec = webClientBuilder.build().post().uri(uri);
```

```
    if (config.getRefresh()) {
        requestBodySpec.header("Refresh-Cache", "true");
    }
```

```
return requestBodySpec
  .header("Authorization", BEARER_TOKEN)
  .body(Mono.just(request), MyRequest.class)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(String.class)
  .block();
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the generic type warning, you can set the generic type as a wildcard (?) ie.

```
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> requestBodySpec = webClient.get().uri("https://google.com");
```

An alternate solution for adding a header based off of a flag in config is to use an ExchangeFilterFunction.

```
public class RefreshExchangeFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    private Config config;

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
        if(config.isRefresh()) {
            return next.exchange(ClientRequest.from(request)
                    .header("Refresh-Cache", "true")
                    .build());
        }
        return next.exchange(request);
    }
}
```

This can then be applied to any/all web clients that need this behaviour

```
WebClient.builder()
         .filter(refreshExchangeFilterFunction)
         .build();
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the downside for using generic type as a wildcard (?) ?

Comment: the return type from `webClient.get()` is `RequestHeadersUriSpec<?>`, so I don't think you have a choice in whether to use the wildcard or not here.